# What is The Best Local DataBase Managment Software?

Tags: database

I Want Implement a Software by C#.net.I want Use a DataBase Manager Software like Access or SqlLite or etc.My Program Saved **Many Data in Local Machine**.
I Do Not Want Publish or Move Data to Other Pcs

What DataBase  Manager Software Must be Choose?

**Not Different DataBase is Free or have a price.**

**what is the Best DataBase Manager Software to Save many Data in Local Machine?**

Comment: how about the amount of data it will be stored ?
are you willing to pay for the database or you want free db ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure you are looking for a free database so for that you can use many databases like mysql ,[postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/) , and sql server [msde](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived/msde/) or access 
but we still have other scenario, if you are going to distribute this application to other pcs so you have to think about deployment and in this case you can eliminate the mysql , postgresql  because they depend on servers but msde (it's also server ) is much easier and you can found alot of tutorials how to deploy it with your project

It depends on how much you are expert in database and for what reason you are using it? are you going to need complex queries or it just a storage place for the data ?

if it's complex query i will go for msde for sql server if it's only for saving information may be i will go for access or even xml

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are developing in C# consider using the MSSql Compact Edition. This allows you to create a local database and use it much like SqlLight. However, the support is much better, especially when you using Visual Studio. There you can find it as LocalDatabase under Data when you adding a new item. (Not 100% sure whether it is present on all versions of VS though).

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has an SQLite Manager add-on.

Comment: Ok

that right
but what is the Best DataBase Manager to Save many Data in Local Machine?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best choice depends on your needs, for example if you must synchronize data with sql server for me the best choise was sql express.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for SQL Express.  You get essentially a scaled down SQL Server that is capable of working with quite a bit of data.  SQL Express plays well with Visual Studio and you will be able to take advantage of the System.Data.SqlClient and related namespaces which come with the .NET framework out of the box.  They are also better than the Odbc namespaces.  Finally, there is a LOT of online support for SQL Express and, as far as I know, SQL Express's flavor of SQL (T-SQL) is the same as that of SQL Server.  So should you one day need the flexibility of running with either or (local database, or server database) you will have it.  Also, SQL Express is fairly commonly used in the microsoft world so you should be able to find lots of examples, if need by.

Answer (score 0):

TurboDB for .NET from dataweb is a good solution, if you want a powerful engine with stored procedures and professional support from the manufacturer:
http://www.dataweb.de/en/products/dotnet_database.html